# Google Maps AuthenticationService denying maps loading in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I've run into some basic trouble implementing Angular Google Maps into my application.
At first I thought it was my app code but this plunker demonstrates the same problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SWxqso?p=preview

This is almost exactly the Quickstart guide found here: http://angular-google-maps.org/use and for some reason I'm hitting Google's AuthenticationService when the map files are requested.

This seems to be Angular related as similar code outside of the app runs fine without an API key. I've tried everything I can think of (including adding my API key and adding my domains to my API console at Google).

There's another non-working version here too: pitwall.csoutham.com/#/circuit/adelaide (not enough reputation to post more than two links).

Any guidance very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer to a question from yesterday with google-maps implementation, there is a working example in jsfiddle too

[AngularJS - load google map script async in directive for multiple maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246403/angularjs-load-google-map-script-async-in-directive-for-multiple-maps/24246967#24246967)

Comment: Thank you, I've since found https://github.com/dylanfprice/angular-gm which seems to work in a much smoother way.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Southam I know you've switched off, but for posterity sake, your plnkr was missing a closing  for the angular-google-maps import. See your example corrected here, http://plnkr.co/edit/qfhuW9?p=preview .

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the fix on that one. The new one I've found seems 'lighter' and doesn't have a dependency on lodash/underscore so I can't help but feel it's a better fit.