# Google Map API : Cannot read property 'undefined_changed' of undefined

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to load a google map api with angular.
And, i have some problem while loading this one.

Just did everything like they say in the documentation :

```
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(window.document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

and in my body :

```
<body>
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

But, when refreshing my page I got this error (which is a little bit difficult to understand) :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined_changed' of undefined

Does anyone have an idea about what is wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: how did u solve this?

Comment: For me it was just a duplication of a prototype Object.ptorotype.boolToArray, which was added by myself to do some stuff, but the same function was instanciated inside gMap API which rise an error

Comment: thanks for getting back. I had a similar issue where I was extending object to add some functionality to it. Turns out that maps doesn't like it.

Comment: No problem, i've searched a long time for this solution last year ... The solution I've found which seem the best, was to keep my functions, but put them into a specific library and don't adding them into the object prototype to avoid some errors like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find it !

So for those who will have the same problem :

NEVER, never, never, never and never add function to Object like :

Object.prototype.boolToArray = function () {}

Comment: Although this answer does not explain why, I have encounted this error, and Prototyping a function like this causes this error. I cannot say why at this stage. My case was Object.prototype.round = function () {...}

Comment: I think that's because of they use they own version of boolToArray (for me, round for you) which does some stuff.
With adding a new function to the Object prototype that may do something totally different, there is a chance that your function will override the one which is used by google, which make their call to their function problematic

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that google maps api is already loaded when you call the operation?
When loading script, you can include a callback function that is invoked when the maps api has loaded:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initialize"></script>
```

a good example of how to use google maps in angular directive:
[AngularJS - load google map script async in directive for multiple maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246403/angularjs-load-google-map-script-async-in-directive-for-multiple-maps)

Comment: I tried to include the callback, but nothing change )= 
I'm going to see this example, maybe i will find the solution ! Thanks

Comment: In fact, it seems that the error occur when I add the <script> in order to include google Map API in my index.html.

Comment: in a script tag, but as I said, the problem was about extending Object with a function boolToArray.
It seems that Google Map API doesn't really like that