# Google Maps lazy loading in angularjs with dynamic geo coordinate updates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I created a `directive` for lazy loading `google maps` with `angularjs`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1NpquJ?p=preview

Taken from:
[AngularJS - load google map script async in directive for multiple maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246403/angularjs-load-google-map-script-async-in-directive-for-multiple-maps)

**Question:** How can I dynamically bind the `lat/long` values to a controller, so that every time the values in the controller change, the map also changes the view?
(eg a backend call serves new *lat/long* values, which must then be pushed to the map element).

I added to the maps directive:

```
  scope: {
      lat: '=',
      long: '='
  }
```

And bind it twoway with:

```
<div lat="{{lat}}" long="{{long}}" />
```

Controller:

```
$http..getBackendData()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.lat = data.lat;
        $scope.long = data.long;
    }
);
...
```

Anyways the map only shows up with the initial value, but is never updated. Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/U31poBpHTfFVQsipLrI4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For now it works adding a `$watch` on `latitude`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eS18B0Te2l5qaf6wvQIH?p=preview

```
scope.$watch('lat', function (newVal) {
    initializeMap();
});
```

But I don't know if this is the correct approach. Feel free to comment if you have betters solutions.